# Mirror OS X sound on Android without WiFi?

Tags: airplay

The audio jack hole on my Mac is broken.

My Android phone's hotspot is my Internet connection, and I don't have any other WiFi. Is there any way I can have the phone mirror the sound of my Mac?

I have already tried Bluetooth,  but I use several other Bluetooth devices at the same time,  and the Bluetooth sound gets a significant delay after some time. I work with creating subtitles for movies, and therefore that time delay is unacceptable to me.

Please note that many of the apps that do this require a WiFi hosted by a third device (router.) I don't have that, and need to do it without it.

I know this is technically doable,  because when I host a hotspot and connect the Mac to it, an app called AirDroid works fine (without using any cellular data) with a transfer speed of 5 megabytes per second. I'm looking for exactly that kind of connection being used to mirror the Mac audio on the phone.

I would even be interested in doing it with a USB cable. I'm interested in minimal delay and fair sound quality.

The phone is a Samsung I9305 running rooted stock 4.4.4 with Xposed Framework installed.

The Mac is running OS X 10.10.1.

I would prefer not having to buy any new hardware.

Comment: Is DLNA not an option?

Comment: It might be, this is the first time I hear of it, could you offer a link to an appropriate tutorial?

Comment: User Izzy maintains a list of DLNA/UPnP server and clients [here](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_dlna?lang=en). Could be helpful to you. You need to host a DLNA/UPnP server on your OS X and a client as an app in your Android. [Kodi](http://kodi.tv/download/) appears to have support for OS X. Note that you've not clearly confirmed whether you want to stream media from OS X to Android or want to make Android act as an alternative to physical speakers. DLNA takes care of former part.

Comment: Yes, I want to use the Android phone as an alternative to the Mac's audio jack. As I mentioned in OP, I work with creating subtitles for movies, and my Mac's audio jack is broken. I wish to plug headphones into the phone, and hear the sound of OS X with minimal delay.

Comment: This does not answer the question, but should solve your problem at minimal cost and in the most efficient way possible: use a USB headset! You can find many for less than $25. Or even cheaper, there are USB-to-audio-jack adapters, available for less than $10.

Comment: It's a good idea, and I already ordered one of those adapters online for a few dollars. (I do want to use my favourite pair of headphones.) The reviews of the adapter said the sound quality was kinda fair, not too good, not terrible. Anyway, I figure my phone has better sound quality than that card.